# Search JPanel by name

Tags: java, swing, assertj

I was following the [How to use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) Java Swing tutorial and I got to the point where the panel is added to the layout:

```java
JPanel cards;
final static String BUTTONPANEL = "Card with JButtons";

//Create the "cards".
JPanel card1 = new JPanel();

//Create the panel that contains the "cards".
cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
cards.add(card1, BUTTONPANEL);
```

Also they say:

> To add a component to a container that a CardLayout object manages,
> specify a string that identifies the component being added. For
> example, in this demo, the first panel has the string "Card with
> JButtons"

So if that string is used to identify the component being added I was wondering if there was a way to get a specific panel in the layout from an AssertJ Swing `FrameFixture` or directly from the `JFrame` object, passing the string.

I see that the `add` method is inherited from `java.awt.Container`. I was expecting to find a method that would allow me to do something like `frame.getComponent(BUTTONPANEL)` but that method expects an index as parameter. Did I overlook something?

Also I'm aware of the fact that I could just do `card1.setName(BUTTONPANEL)` and then in my tests retrieve it with:

```java
window = new FrameFixture(view);
window.panel(BUTTONPANEL);
```

But what's the point of setting that string in the `add` method if there is no use for it.
Thanks.

**Edit:**

I had missed the fact that of course the string `BUTTONPANEL` it it is used to change the panel from the card layout, like this:

```java
cardLayout.show(getContentPane(), BUTTONPANEL);
```

And so obviously that string has a use.

However I was looking for a way to be able to get the `JPanel` object by calling a method on the `JFrame` or `FrameFixture` object, passing the string. Something like this:

```java
JPanel buttonPanelPanel = frame.getPanelFromName(BUTTONPANEL);
```

This is because within the tests I don't have a direct access to the panels, but only to the frame. In order to make assertions on a particular panel I wanted to be able to perform a get of the panel with the string used in `add`. But maybe this is not possible.

Comment: I don't understand what you're searching for.  The `CardLayout` `show` method shows the `JPanel` you specify by the `String`.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc yes, you're right, my bad, the `String` allows to change the panel. But I was searching for a way to use that same `String` to get the JPanel object by calling a method on the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a method to the `MainPanel` class to return a `JPanel` when you pass a `String`.  I don't use the method, but it's there.

I made all the additional classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CardPanelExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CardPanelExample());
    }
    
    private final MainPanel mainPanel;
    
    public CardPanelExample() {
        this.mainPanel = new MainPanel(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("CardPanel Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(mainPanel.getPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void setNextPanel() {
        mainPanel.setNextPanel();
    }
    
    public JPanel getPanelFromName(String name) {
        return mainPanel.getPanelFromName(name);
    }
    
    public class MainPanel {
        
        private final CardLayout cardLayout;
        
        private final JPanel panel;
        private JPanel yellowPanel, orangePanel, whitePanel;
        
        private final String[] panelStrings;
        private String currentPanelString;
        
        public MainPanel(CardPanelExample view) {
            this.cardLayout = new CardLayout();
            this.panelStrings = new String[] { "alpha", "beta", "gamma" };
            this.currentPanelString = panelStrings[0];
            this.panel = createMainPanel(view, cardLayout, panelStrings);
        }
        
        private JPanel createMainPanel(CardPanelExample view, 
                CardLayout cardLayout, String[] panelStrings) {
            this.yellowPanel = new ColorPanel(view, Color.YELLOW).getPanel();
            this.orangePanel = new ColorPanel(view, Color.ORANGE).getPanel();
            this.whitePanel = new ColorPanel(view, Color.WHITE).getPanel();
            
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
            panel.add(yellowPanel, panelStrings[0]);
            panel.add(orangePanel, panelStrings[1]);
            panel.add(whitePanel, panelStrings[2]);
            
            return panel;
        }
        
        public JPanel getPanelFromName(String name) {
            if (name.equals(panelStrings[0])) {
                return yellowPanel;
            } else if (name.equals(panelStrings[1])) {
                return orangePanel;
            } else if (name.equals(panelStrings[2])) {
                return whitePanel;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        
        
        public void setNextPanel() {
            for (int index = 0; index < panelStrings.length; index++) {
                if (currentPanelString.equals(panelStrings[index])) {
                    index = ++index % panelStrings.length;
                    currentPanelString = panelStrings[index];
                    cardLayout.show(panel, currentPanelString);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        public JPanel getPanel() {
            return panel;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class ColorPanel {
        
        private final JPanel panel;
        
        public ColorPanel(CardPanelExample view, Color backgroundColor) {
            this.panel = createMainPanel(view, backgroundColor);
        }
        
        private JPanel createMainPanel(CardPanelExample view, Color backgroundColor) {
            JPanel panel  = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            panel.setBackground(backgroundColor);
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(25, 150, 25, 150));
            
            JButton button = new JButton("Next Panel");
            button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(view));
            panel.add(button);
            
            return panel;
        }

        public JPanel getPanel() {
            return panel;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        
        private final CardPanelExample view;

        public ButtonListener(CardPanelExample view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            view.setNextPanel();
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, however this is not quite what I was looking for. I've edited my question to make it (hopefully) more clear.

Comment: @claudia: See my updated answer.